# accessing ID of mysql insert during the insert

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to access the id of the auto increment for use inside the query.

for instance Wordpress puts the id of the insert in the GUID of the same row, is there any way i can access the id that the row will take during the insertion.

Or maybe there is some quick way for me to find out what the current AI counter is at, so I know what the one going in will be?

I need this because I am trying to backfill the WP posts table into a new custom post type I am using, and I need to have the id of the insert to put inside the GUID column.

Comment: for instance "INSERT INTO table (id,name,adress,auto_val) VALUES (null,'John','10 sycamore lane','MYSQL_AUTO_INCREMENT')"

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I ended up just pulling out the last id like so:

```
$this->lID = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1"));
        $this->lID = $this->lID[ID];
```

Comment: That's bad. Other connections could insert rows between your SELECT and your INSERT, unless you LOCK the table.

Comment: This will probably cause you problems in the long run as a Alessandro indicates

Comment: You are right, but I needed this for a one off query to insert old data into a new database before the site is live, so no problems there.

Comment: This answer is no different than all the LAST_INSERT_ID answers from above and yet you chose this one? Why?

Comment: use last_insert_id().  In normal operation there is no problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the mysql LAST_INSERT_ID() function can help you.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: will LAST_INSERT_ID() return the id of the currently inserted row ?

Comment: It will not. It will return first ID inserted using last INSERT query.

Comment: Well. LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1 gives the new insert id :)

Comment: @Radoslav Georgiev: Don't ever do that. You have no guarantee that other connections didn't insert new rows in the meanwhile (LAST_INSERT_ID() works per connection). Not to mention, it might be the ID from quite another table. Last but not least, server might be set up to increment IDs by more than 1.

Comment: @Mhcl, thanks for the advice ;) This solution won't even come to my mind but it seemed like a choice. (bad choice)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want some sort of column with the same value as the user ID.
But why should you do that? just use the user ID, even if you use it for example as the refer ID.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't access the auto_increment value of a row being inserted. I suggest to insert the row, then read its ID and update it to fill the fields that you need to know the ID for.

(Why do you need that? It seems your database needs some normalization, if you have such an egg-chicken problem.)

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it. This worked for me:

1) just execute 2 separate MySql queries. The first one inserts the post values into the wp_posts table. You should insert into all columns except in the column "guid" insert some placeholder, like "0".

2) the second query is executed right after the first one and here you can call the LAST_INSERT_ID() function to get the true last insert ID of the previous query. This second query updates the "guid" field with the right ID number.

You can insert this into the loop for mass-inserting of WP posts from csv file for example.

**You should do this when the site is off-line or lock the tables first so no other query request comes in between form somewhere else.**

Example: 1st query (sorry for the column formatting but it is easier to debug):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_posts(
            ID,
            post_author,
            post_date,
            post_date_gmt,
            post_content,
            post_title,
            post_excerpt,
            post_status,
            comment_status,
            ping_status,
            post_password,
            post_name,
            to_ping,
            pinged,
            post_modified,
            post_modified_gmt,
            post_content_filtered,
            post_parent,
            guid,
            menu_order,
            post_type,
            post_mime_type,
            comment_count
            ) VALUES (
            'null',
            '1',
            '$timestmp',
            '$timestmp',
            '$content',
            '$posttitle',
            '',
            'publish',
            'open',
            'open',
            '',
            '$postname',
            '',
            '',
            '$timestmp',
            '$timestmp',
            '',
            '0',
            '$uiai',
            '0',
            'post',
            '',
            '0'
            )") or die(mysql_error());
```

2nd query:

```
$uid = mysql_insert_id();
$uiai = 'http://yoursite.net/wordpress/?post_type=post&#038;p='.$uid;
mysql_query("UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = '$uiai' WHERE ID = '$uid'");
```

...also, when you are looping through many inserts, sometimes it can max out the maximum allowed execution time for PHP script and the upload gets interrupted. It helps to use set_time_limit(0); throughout the script so the max allowed time counter is regularly reset.

...hope this helps :)

Comment: Does this still work if someone else inserts a row before the second query executes? I wouldn't want to accidentally update the row after what I intended.

Comment: ..no, it should not. but the chances of another query coming in between when both parts of this script are executed from the same file are slim. However on high-traffic systems, I would suggest to set it off-line for the time of the update or if you are using inno DB then at least lock it up.

Comment: I needed this for a different purpose, though I realize my code logic was a little paradoxical and I opted for a different (probably better) approach.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use `AUTO_INCREMENT` value of your table in `information_schema.tables` in an `INSERT ... SELECT` query. In theory `INSERT ... SELECT` should lock `information_schema.tables` and `AUTO_INCREMENT` value should be the Id which is used for next `INSERT`. But you should hardly test this and consider performance issues.

Answer (score -1):

```
use mysql_insert_id() to get last inserted id
```

You can see more information at:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: He is asking for a way to read and use the ID of the row being inserted with the current query. `INSERT INTO table VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID())` won't work.